# Format row if date in one cell is within 7 days - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm new to Google Sheets, ready to pound my head against the wall in frustration.

I would like to change the color of the row if the date in column k is within the next 7 days.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you add some of the code you currently have, so there is something to work with ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use conditional formatting on the date column.

For example if your dates are in column A, then highlight column A then select from the Format menu Conditional Formatting:

then under the Format cells if... select Is Between, then type the formula =today()+7
=today()

in the two boxes. 
[Conditional formatting between today() dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtfhA.png)